# Display div element in two rows with 4 items in a row

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am diplaying four bootstrap cards dynamically from a foreach loop in asp.net core mvc. The issue is that I have a main div that wraps two element to form a column.

My code is as follows:

```
        @{
            int count = 0;

            foreach (var item in Model)
            {

                    <div class="statistics col-lg-3 col-12">

                    <div class="statistic d-flex align-items-center bg-white has-shadow">
                        <div class="icon bg-green"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i></div>
                        <div class="text"><strong>@item.ApplicationName</strong><br><small>@item.ApplicationDescription</small></div>
                    </div>
}
```

In static html, the div are arranged like this:

```
<div class="statistics col-lg-3 col-12">
                <div class="statistic d-flex align-items-center bg-white has-shadow">
                    <div class="icon bg-red"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i></div>
                    <div class="text"><strong>SPRES</strong><br><small>Track your time</small></div>
                </div>
                <div class="statistic d-flex align-items-center bg-white has-shadow">
                    <div class="icon bg-blue"><i class="fa fa-calendar-o"></i></div>
                    <div class="text"><strong>LMS</strong><br><small>Plan your leaves</small></div>
                </div>

            </div>
```

Hence, making a column.

From my loop I have 8 items.

I want to wrap it as follows:

```
Item1 Item3 Item5 Item7
Item2 Item4 Item6 Item8
```

and if the loop has more items than eight items (like I only want four items in a row, if it is more, then continue on another row), continue on a new row. How can I achieve this logic in asp.net / c# ? Please help

Comment: Please try `margin: 2%; flex-basis: 21%;`(or increase flex-bases without margin) to your statistic css class and `flex-wrap: wrap;` to your statistics css class. Edit: If that works let me know, so I can come back with a solution that uses bootstrap's classes.